# Javascript works with HTML but not in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, variables, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use a free bootstrap template (http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/) in my Rails 4 application (https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-agency).  When I copy the Javascript files to my `app/assets/javascripts`, `cbpAnimatedHeader.js`  complains that `"classie" is not defined`:

```
/**
 * cbpAnimatedHeader.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-default' ),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 300;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
            }
        }, false );
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

When I looked at `classie.js` I saw that `var classie = {...}` is defined inside a function:

```
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

I understand why it is complaining. But then my question is why does everything work fine in it's original HTML format (http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/)? How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question should contain any relevant code inside the body of the question. Questions which require the user to visit other sites are frowned upon since they cause link rot and may be spam or malicious.

Comment: I think your Ruby on Rails app is compiling the CSS and JS. So please, specify your full stack, and which version of it are you using.